# Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’ Execution halted

Tags: r, ubuntu

I updated my system from ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10. everything worked fine on my previous version, but updating removed all my R libraries.

I want to reinstall them, but when I try and install anything, i.e.

```
install.packages("data.table")
Installing package into ‘/home/sam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com/src/contrib/data.table_1.11.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 3262853 bytes (3.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.1 MB

Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
Execution halted

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpYnxoaQ/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("data.table") :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status
```

I get some error about ggplot2 not being present, even though i'm not trying to install it. Currently I haven't managed to isntall any libraries.

I am using `R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"`. which is the most recent version.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: No, idea. Is this a vanilla R session without any loading of old work spaces or Rprofile.site (or similar configuration) file?

Comment: It looks like `R` is trying to install dependecies which it can't find. You seem to use a different repo than me (it works on my Ubuntu machine). Can you try `install.packages("data.table", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")`?

Comment: @Roland Actually I didn't know what vanilla R is, normally I just hit 'R' in the terminal and go from there. But I just tried starting R --vanilla and the packages installed properly. But when I go back into just starting with 'R', the same errors appear

Comment: So, R was loading something at start-up as I suspected. Find the file that is loaded and look at its content.

Comment: @JBGruber ggplot2 is not in data.table's dependency tree.

Comment: @Roland - is there a way of finding out which files R is sourcing on start up? I haven't set up an.Rprofile yet..

Comment: Search your system for the files `Rprofile.site`, `.Rprofile`, and `.Rdata`. (I've rarely used R from a linux command line.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Roland was correct - the issue here was that I was trying to load libraries from my `.Rprofile` that weren't installed. Removing these lines from the `.Rprofile` stopped the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your R version and do this but you'll need install all packages again:

Tool > Global Options > R version (CHANGE) > Select "Use your machine's default version of R..."

Answer (score 0):

I did two things and it's work. Hopefully, it does for you also

1. a) Update your R and do this.
   `Tool > Global Options > R version (CHANGE) > Select "Choose the specific version of R..."`. Mostly just choose the latest version.
   b) Restart your app after.
2. Install `ggplot2` using this command:

```
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)  
library(ggplot2)
```